# Show that Jacobi Method does not converge for $ \frac{1}{2}\lt a \lt 1 $ in the given matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that 
\begin{align}
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & a & a \\
a & 1 & a \\
a & a & 1
\end{array} } \right]
\end{align} 
is a symmetric positive definite for $ \frac{1}{2}\lt a \lt 1 $, but that the Jacobi Method does not converge for $\frac{1}{2}\lt a \lt 1 $. 
$$\textbf{MY ATTEMPT} $$
I know that since $A$ is SDP, $det(A) \gt 0$. Using the splitting $A=D-L-U$. I have that
\begin{align} D^{-1}(L+U) = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -a & -a \\
-a & 0 & -a \\
-a & -a & 0
\end{array} } \right]
\end{align}
Therefore, if the $p(D^{-1}(L+U)) \lt 1$, matrix $A$ is convergent with Jacobi Method. Otherwise, it is not. 
Thus, I have the following characteristic polynomial from which I intent to obtain the eigenvalues and conclude whether the matrix is convergent with Jacobi method or not.
$$ - \lambda^3 + 3a^2 \lambda - 2a^3 = 0 $$

So my questions are:

(1) Is my approach to the question correct ? If yes

(2) How do I solve for the eigenvalues from the above cubic equation.

Please I need help friends! Thanks.

Comment: When you speak about convergence for Jacobi's method, you mean convergence for any initial approximation right? because the method can be convergent for some initial approximations and divergent for others...

Comment: @PierreCarre Intuitively yes. Since it is not explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: Ok, so you are on the right track... The eigenvalues are $a, -2a$ and so the spectral radius of the iteration matrix is $2a$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a viable approach. Now you can get one eigenvalue fairly easily by guess-and-check (this might be easier by thinking about when $D^{-1}(L+U)-\lambda I$ will be singular rather than looking at the characteristic polynomial), after which you can long-divide to find the other two eigenvalues.

If you are still stuck, here is a slightly more specific hint: the eigenvalue that you can find by guess-and-check involves $a$...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It was helpful.